# How to disable gmail important?

Tags: gmail

I mainly use gmail through IMAP. For somereason gmail has been skipping the inbox and going straight to important with some messages. I don't use important so might as well disable it. Where is the setting to disable it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please login to your gmail and follow steps :

1 - Login to your gmail

2 - Go to setting

3 - Go to Labels

4 - You will get label "Important" with option Show & Hide , You can Hide it from here.

Comment: What does the option "show in IMAP" do? For example is it possible to have a label not show in gmail the web interface but show in a email client like Outlook?

Comment: I do not have idea about that..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> General and set Personal Level Indicators to No Indicators. Gmail should now stop assigning the Important indicator to any emails.